# best practice to handle unhandled exception in WCF project?

Tags: wcf, flourinefx

I have a WCF project which handles all my requests from a flex application.
the project has about 30 methods. what is the best practice to handle all the exceptions? for the most parts it's for logging only.
warp each method with try/catch (and maybe have more data for logging) or handle in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want to implement IErrorHandler interface to handle unhandled exceptions. Have a lookt at this article for more details [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx)